# Select Table Rows by Grouping them Adjacent to each Other using XPath

Tags: c#, xpath

I am not clear how to express my problem correctly in the question so forgive me if I am not able to properly convey my problem. I have following data.

```
<tr class="header">Random Value 1</tr>
<tr class="item">1</tr>
<tr class="item">2</tr>
<tr class="item">3</tr>
<tr class="header">Random Value 2</tr>
<tr class="item">4</tr>
<tr class="item">5</tr>
<tr class="item">6</tr>
<tr class="header">Random Value 3</tr>
<tr class="item">7</tr>
<tr class="item">8</tr>
<tr class="item">9</tr>
```

What I want to acheive is that I want to select the  with class header. I have achieved this by using the following line of code,

```
HtmlNodeCollection headerNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='header']");
```

Now I have all the header rows in the collection. Now I loop through all the header nodes and I want to get the table rows which are adjacent to the respective header rows.

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in headerNodes)
{
     HtmlNodeCollection itemNodes = ???
}
```

My question is that what I should write here so that for header row with text "Random Value 1" I get the item rows 1,2 and 3. Similarly for header row with text "Random Value 2" I get the item row 4,5 and 6 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem after a lot of searching and playing with different options. The trick was to select the rows with class "item" by checking the preceding header row. So you can see in the XPath expression that I am selecting a tr with class "item" and I am also checking that its preceding tr with should have class "header" must have innerText value of current header HtmlNode. This does the trick.

```
foreach (HtmlNode header in headerNodes)
{
   string xPath = "following-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'item') and preceding-sibling::tr[@class='header'][1]='{0}']";
   HtmlNodeCollection itemRows = header.SelectNodes(String.Format(xPath, header.InnerText));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what HtmlNodeCollection is, but if you use normal XPath and do SelectNodes (which would return an XmlNodeCollection) than you would find the elements you're looking for with node.NextSibling.
So, your loop would look something like:

```
   foreach (XmlNode node in headerNodes)
   {
        string entry = node.NextSibling.InnerXml;
   }
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell that I am using HtmlAgilityPack and HtmlNodeCollection is used to get the Nodes. You answer is only valid for getting 1 next sibling. The item rows could be more or less and I need to get all item rows after a header row. I have found the answer and mentioning it for others.

Comment: Right, you'd need to store your current node somewhere inside the loop, like: